# Adding Photodiode to LTspice

Tags: ltspice, photodiode, library, model

I am very new to LTspice. I would like to ask "How can I add a **photodiode** in the Ltspice?" Is ideal photodiode (or any specific) model already included in the LTspice or do I need to create third party model for photodiode? If it is *already included*, under with categories it is included in library ? Or If it is *not included*, how can I make one? Do I need to create the spice model of photodiode which will consist (roughly) of a current source, capacitor and resistor then refer back to the photodiode? Or if there is another way around can you please share your knowledge?

Comment: LTSpice doesn't model optical events, perhaps model it as a programmed current source?

Comment: ahhh.. I see. So I can use a current source (may be in parallel with capacitor) instead of photodiode?

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to get a photodiode, *and to control it*, is to use one of the built-in optocouplers.
The base/collector junction of a phototransistor is a photodiode (just ignore the emitter):

[image: optocoupler as photodiode]

Or use the `4N2x.sub`/`CNY17.sub` as a model to build your own subcircuit.

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to find a photodiode model on the internet as the .SUBCKT model. You can add such a model directly to the diagram and connect it under the diode symbol.

On my blog it is more visually described:

http://sigaris-electronics.eu/2018/11/ltspice-adding-an-element-model-to-the-schema/